# How to get active image name from a slider using php

Tags: javascript, php

I am using "jssor" slider, which is getting the image from a folder directory, the code is something like

```
<div>
    <img name="galleryImage" class="galleryOpen" onclick="galleryOpen()" data-u="image" src="<?php echo $sliderDir; ?><?php echo $folderPath[$i]; ?>" />
</div>
```

Now I want to get the active image name from the slider which is changing after 2 seconds, and wanting to display the name to a `<p>` tag, and when the slide will change the name of `<p>` tag also be changed. I have used the below code to get the name

```
$filename = pathinfo($_FILES['galleryImage']['name'], PATHINFO_FILENAME);
```

But it giving an error like `Undefined index: galleryImage in C:\xampp\htdocs\...`

Can anyone help please? Thank you

Comment: `<?php echo $sliderDir; ?><?php echo $folderPath[$i]; ?>` Does this really a valid Image File?

Comment: PHP is serverside, your Javascript slider is clientside.

Comment: `$_FILES` has to do with _file uploads_, which is absolutely not what you are dealing with here to begin with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may solve the problem by following. Thank you all

```
var imageUrl = document.getElementById("galleryImage").getAttribute("src");
```